# Pig Programming Logic

Tags: apache-pig

```
10278929012|HDFC1001|SBI|2014-08-03|8000|S
10278929012|HDFC1001|HDFC|2014-08-17|500|S
```

I need to find out if the atm_id belongs to the same bank then I need a indicator to be  produced

I need output like this

```
10278929012|HDFC1001|SBI|diff_bank
10278929012|HDFC1001|HDFC|same_bank


atm_trans = LOAD '/user/cloudera/inputfiles/atm_trans.txt' USING PigStorage('|') as(accnt_no:long,atm_id:chararray,bank_name :chararray,date:chararray,amt:chararray,status:chararray);

atm_trans_each = foreach atm_trans generate accnt_no,atm_id,bank_name,(bank_name matches atm_id ?'same_bank' : 'diff_bank') as ind;

dump atm_trans_each;
```

but I am getting syntax error. Can somebody correct it give me the correct statement to get the ouput;

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

**input.txt**

```
10278929012|HDFC1001|SBI|2014-08-03|8000|S
10278929012|HDFC1001|HDFC|2014-08-17|500|S
```

**PigScript:**

```
atm_trans = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage('|') as(accnt_no:long,atm_id:chararray,bank_name:chararray,date:chararray,amt:chararray,status:chararray);
atm_trans_each = foreach atm_trans generate accnt_no,atm_id,bank_name,((STARTSWITH(atm_id,bank_name)== true)?'same_bank':'diff_bank') as ind;
STORE atm_trans_each INTO 'output' USING PigStorage('|');
```

**Update: In 0.8 version**

```
atm_trans_each = foreach atm_trans generate accnt_no,atm_id,bank_name,((REGEX_EXTRACT(atm_id,'([A-Za-z]+)',1) == bank_name)?'same_bank':'diff_bank');
```

**output:**

```
10278929012|HDFC1001|SBI|diff_bank
10278929012|HDFC1001|HDFC|same_bank
```

Comment: Ok.but STARTSWITH is not with pig 0.8 version. Is there anyway to achieve in Pig 0.8  I am trying the below , but that does not works  atm_trans_each = foreach atm_trans generate accnt_no,atm_id,bank_name,(bank_name matches CONCAT(SUBSTRING(atm_id,0,4),'.*') ?'same_bank' :'diff_bank') as ind;

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will try this . Nice thinking

Comment: It works. but i have one question ((REGEX_EXTRACT(atm_id,'([A-Za-z]+)',1). what is the use of second paramter. that is '([A-Za-z]+)'why is it the symbol + is given there. Can you please explain the second paramter alone

Comment: Here atm_id values is nothing but sequence of characters followed by numbers (ie HDFC1001). I want to extract only the characters(HDFC) so i am using regex [A-Za-z]+  which means match only the characters (A to Z) &(a to z) and + means match 1 or more consecutive characters. In this case the above regex will match the consecutive characters ie "HDFC" and numbers "1001" will be skipped.

Comment: Perfect..Thanks for the clean explanation

Comment: Cool.Please accept the answer, so that i will be easy for me to track the answered vs unanswered questions.